# Does $E(Y)=0$ hold in this setting?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, expected-value

Given two continuous random variables $X$ and $Y$ with the same support, we have $E(X)=0$ and $Y\leq|X|$. Does this setting imply $E(Y)=0$?

My proof: $Y\leq|X|\Longrightarrow -X\leq Y\leq X \Longrightarrow 0=-E(X)\leq E(Y)\leq E(X) = 0 \Longrightarrow E(Y)=0$. Does this make sense?

Comment: If $-X \le Y \le X$ always holds, then $-X \le X$ always holds, so we always have $X \ge 0$. The only way this can coexist with $\mathbb E[X]=0$ is if $X=0$ with probability $1$, and we can only have $-X \le Y \le X$ in that case if $Y=0$ with probability $1$. This gives us $\mathbb E[Y]=0$, certainly, but I feel like you did not mean this trivial case. Did you mean $|Y| \le |X|$?

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$Y \leq |X|$ does not imply that $-X \leq Y \leq X$.

For a counter-example think of the case $Y=X \sin X$ if $X >0$ and $Y=-X$ if $X \leq 0$ with $X \sim N(0,1)$.

Comment: Your counterexample doesn't work because $Y$ does not have the same support as $X$, a condition required by the problem.

Comment: @heropup Thanks. I have modified my example. With a little effort we can show that $EY \neq 0$.

Answer (score 3):

Counterexample:
$$\begin{align}
X&\sim\text{Normal}(0,1)\\[1ex]
Y&=X\,e^{-X}\\[1ex]
\mathbb E[Y]&=-\sqrt{e}\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 2):

The other answers provide good counterexamples saying why your statement cannot be true. I just wanted to go into more detail pointing out the flaw in your logic.

While it is true that $|Y|\le X\implies -X\le Y\le X$, it is not the case that $Y\le |X|$ implies $-X\le Y\le X$. I think this summarizes the mistake you made.

Instead, $Y\le |X|$ implies
$$
Y\le 0\quad \text{or}\quad 0\le Y\le X \quad \text{or}\quad 0\le Y\le -X.
$$

Answer (score 1):

If $Y$ and $X$ share the same support but are not necessarily identically distributed, there is no reason why you should have $\operatorname{E}[Y] = 0$.  Moreover, it is not clear what you mean by $Y \le |X|$ because $X$ and $Y$ are random variables.

If what you mean is $$\Pr[Y \le |X|] = 1,$$ then it is still not true:  for example, let $U \sim \operatorname{Uniform}(0,1)$, and then define $$X = U - 1/2, \\Y \mid X = (X + 1/2)B - 1/2,$$ where $B \sim \operatorname{Beta}(2,3)$.  Then $X$ obviously has zero mean, and the unconditional distribution of $Y$ has support on $(-1/2,1/2)$, the same as $X$, since $Y$ attains its maximum when $U = B = 1$ and its minimum when $B = 0$.  Since $Y$ depends on $X$, $$\Pr[Y \le |X|] = \Pr[UB  \le |U - 1/2| + 1/2],$$ and the triangle inequality gives $$|U-1/2| + |1/2| \ge |U - 1/2 + 1/2| = |U| = U \ge UB,$$ hence this probability equals $1$.

But $$\operatorname{E}[Y] = \operatorname{E}[\operatorname{E}[(X + 1/2)B - 1/2 \mid X]] = \operatorname{E}[(X + 1/2)\operatorname{E}[B] - 1/2] = \frac{2}{5}\operatorname{E}[X] - \frac{3}{10} = -\frac{3}{10} \ne 0.$$

Comment: The sentence $Y\le |X|$ is perfectly clear. $X$ and $Y$ are random variables, which are functions $\Omega\to \Bbb R$. The statement $Y\le |X|$ means that $Y(\omega)\le |X(\omega)|$ for all $\omega\in \Omega$.